# How do I make Visual Studio show objects value inline when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When debugging, I would like to see objects value shown inline as you stepping through each line of code. I've seen this feature in some of my colleagues VS but I could not find any option to turn it on.

Comment: This is most likely due to an add in. I use DevExpress CodeRush and it does this for me. Speak to your colleagues and see what they use. or goto https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ and have a search around

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio cannot do that by itself.

What you have most likely witnessed is the [new Resharper feature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/11/21/resharper-2017-3-brings-debugger-editor/). If your colleagues have this, there is a good chance your company will provide it for you, too. Don't hesitate to ask your manager for a licence, it's a great tool and will make you more productive.

*(Disclaimer: I'm in no way affiliated with the company. I just think they have a great product.)*

Answer (score 0):

The inline hint is a new feature in Visual Studio 16.8. But we have to enable it manually.

1. Go to Tools in the top bar, then click on options.
2. Go to Text Editor in the left menu, and expand it.
3. Then go to C# Expand it, and go to advanced.
4. Now in the right-side options go to section Editor help.
5. Enable "Display Inline Parameter name hints (experimental)".

[image]

Comment: that is a different feature, it shows parameter names (not only in debug) and not variables values, there are now many more options of it to configure

Comment: What are those options?

Comment: you can choose what kind of param hints show and when, but still that isnt relevant for this question

Answer (score 0):

I think there are not any free Visual Studio extension to archieve that. There is one called "Entrian Inline Watch" by Entrian Solutions - Richie Hindle, but it is a paid extension.

You can download the trial version for Visual Studio 2022 from this link:
[Entrian Inline Watch For VS2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntrianSolutions-RichieHindle.Entrian-Inline-Watch-64)

And also for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 from this link:
[Entrian Inline Watch For VS 2015, 2017, 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntrianSolutions-RichieHindle.EntrianInlineWatch)

Keep in mind that the trial only lasts 30 days.

Answer (score -1):

In the menu, go to:
`Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Output`

Comment: This isn't what he's asking about. He means in the text editor, a small popup thing appears next to the variable itself (inline), showing the current value.