# How to turn ON visual studio debugger inline watch in vs 2015?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I saw some developer have visual studio inline watch without using any third party plugin. I searched in settings to turn this ON but I can not understand what option will allow me this. 
I can get this feature using Entrain Inline watch but this is a paid software and I know the visual studio has a built-in feature for this. Can you let me know how can I turn this on?
[See the screenshot, I can see the variable values in line using entrain third-party plugin but I want to use the visual studio's built-in option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVnzU.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future referrence, I would like to share one tool that I have found useful, that is Entrian Inline Watch visual studio extension, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm afraid the answer is negative.

For now, Visual Studio2015 doesn't support for watching inline values in debug mode.Please check [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/),it describes several ways to watch values in debug mode without using third-party plugin.

> I saw some developer have visual studio inline watch without using any
>   third party plugin.

As I know, VS2015 doesn't have this option. But VS Code seems to support this feature now. I'm not sure if the developer you mentioned has some extension like Resharper or what. It also provides this feature like Entrain Inline watch.

If you have a requirement to achieve this feature in VS2015, I suggest you post your suggestion on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) by Help=>Send feedback=>Provide a Suggestion, if it gets enough votes, the product team would consider it.

Comment: I already mentioned I saw some developers have the feature. They are using vs 2015 and they are not using any external plugins

Comment: Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005696/how-do-i-make-visual-studio-show-objects-value-inline-when-debugging), please check this [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8240820-display-variable-values-inline-while-debugging), the request of this option didn't get enough votes and has closed. It doesn't support for vs2015 and vs2017. I'm not sure if what you see is a [DataTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/view-data-values-in-data-tips-in-the-code-editor?view=vs-2019).